# How to tryCatch the same function call multiple times (N times) in R

Tags: r, try-catch, try-catch-finally

We have a basic tryCatch that writes a dataframe to Google Sheets, and trys again if the first write fails for any reason:

```
result = tryCatch({
  print('TRYING')
  googlesheets4::sheet_write(data = our_df, ss = our_spreadsheet, sheet = 'our_sheetname')
}, error = function(e) {
  print('ERROR, TRYING AGAIN')
  googlesheets4::sheet_write(data = our_df, ss = our_spreadsheet, sheet = 'our_sheetname')
})
```

It is possible to generalize this code to retry the `googlesheets4::sheet_write()` function call for N number of tries? Is something built into base R for this or is there a good R library that handles unlimited retries of a function?

Comment: `for` loops or `while` loops should work just fine for this.

Comment: if this were put in a for loop, i believe the code would throw an error the first time that `googlesheets4::sheet_write()` fails to run in the `error = function(e) {}` error function.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying it's quite as easy as `for(i in 1:10) {{your exact code}}`. You would use a different error function and rely on the loop to re-try, not the error function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it in a for loop like this.

First, I am going to define a function that often fails (as I don't have access to your Google sheet).

```r
russian_roulette <- function(n = 6) {
    revolver <- sample(1:n, 1)
    if (revolver == 1) {
        return("You lived")
    } else {
        stop("Better luck next time...")
    }
}
```

Then you can try it as many times as you consider reasonable. You can replace my call to `russian_roulette()` with your call to `googlesheets4::sheet_write()`.

```
NUM_TRIES <- 10

for (i in 1:NUM_TRIES) {
    message(i)
    result <- try({
        russian_roulette()
    })
    if (class(result) != "try-error") {
        print("Success!")
        break
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
Error in russian_roulette() : Better luck next time...
2
Error in russian_roulette() : Better luck next time...
3
Error in russian_roulette() : Better luck next time...
4
Error in russian_roulette() : Better luck next time...
5
Error in russian_roulette() : Better luck next time...
6
[1] "Success!"

result
# [1] "You lived"
```

I don't know why you expect writing to a file to fail - depending on the reason you may want to add a `Sys.sleep()` call in there for a certain number of seconds after every failure.

Comment: Excellent point on the `Sys.sleep()` comment. There are very few situations where trying the exact same code again immediately will produce a better result. If a file-write sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, letting a little bit of time pass between tries seems smart.